# htaccess rewrite rule: setting first parameter as optional

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set the first rule as optional, so both of these URLs will work:

- /username
- /username/history
- /history

The username will never clash.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/((history|analysis|messages|photos)?)$ pages/dashboard.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

With the above I have `/username/history` working. Cannot figure howto get the others.

**EDIT:** The above snippet is the result of trying to merge these three lines into one.

```
RewriteRule ^(history|analysis|messages|photos)?$ pages/dashboard.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(history|analysis|messages|photos)?$ pages/dashboard.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ pages/dashboard.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(history|analysis|messages|photos)/?$ pages/dashboard.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(?:/(history|analysis|messages|photos))?/?$ pages/dashboard.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for /history and /username/history, but not /username.

Comment: It works! I was trying to do one 1 RewriteRule though, but knocking down 3 to 2 is a start.

Comment: Yes merging into one might be risky also since it can match unwanted texts. 2 rules are still safe.